# Laravel 5.7 E-Mail Verification Class 'DOMDocument' not found

Tags: php, domdocument, laravel-5.7

I have a laravel project that uses the default Laravel E-mail verification, but when clicking the resend e-mail verification link it gives me this error:

**Class 'DOMDocument' not found**

I'm using CentOS 6.9 php.71w-xml is already installed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14395239/class-domdocument-not-found

Comment: Hi, I already have php-xml installed on my server.

Comment: @RonronAsistores Have you checked link provided by Hamelraj

Comment: plz check `phpinfo();`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774581/how-to-test-whether-simplexml-is-installed-on-my-php-or-not

Comment: I've checked it my SimpleXML isn't enabled. Do I need to enable it?

Comment: I have checked and enabled everything that is needed. But still the error persists. I re-installed my php, still nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all

It's Working now. I just Removed php* on yum exclude then install php-xml. *facepalmed.